# Rails render contact form in other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, render, contact-form

I have two controllers Pages and Contact. Pages shows up stuff from database. Contact is simple contact form and works good. Now i want to put this contact form in specific page. But i try to render this and still got errors like no model class etc.

this is my Contact controller (controllers/contact_controller):

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @message = Message.new
    end

  def create
      @message = Message.new(params[:message])

      if @message.valid?
        NotificationMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
        redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Sent.")
      else
        flash.now.alert = "Alert."
        render :new
      end
  end

end
```

This is my message model (models/message.rb):

```
class Message

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :body

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

and this is the form (views/contact/new.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
  <fieldset class="fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :email %>
      <%= form.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :subject %>
      <%= form.text_field :subject %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :body %>
      <%= form.text_area :body %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

How to put this form to pages view???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use partials. Instead of put the form in contact/new, you could, for example, put it in a file called 'app/views/shared/_message_form.html.erb' and then in contact/new (and all other pages):
`render 'shared/message_form'`

Obviously, you have to set `@message` in each controllers which views render this partial. Maybe you can have a method in your ApplicationController like `set_message` and call it when needs.
Simple Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def set_message
    @message = Message.new params[:message] || {}
  end
end
```

And then you can use `set_message` in any controllers :)

Comment: but what to do with the :url => contact_path? Shoudl i leave it?

Comment: and how to do this set_message :)

Comment: For the url, I think you want the request to always go to contacts controller, so yes, you can leave contact_path.  
For the set_message, I've updated the answer.

Comment: getting undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class but when i set the set_message as helper_method in application controller and put there whole code from contact_controller create then the form is showing up on pages but don`t working

Comment: Have you called `set_message` in your PagesController and ContactController? Update the controller as they are know, and post your page views where you want to use the form :)

Comment: this is show in pages controller

    def show
        @page = Page.find(params[:id])
        @message = :set_message
    end

and it`s shows up the form only if put this like that, the view is renedring well.

But when i click send i have error:

     NoMethodError in ContactController#create
    
    undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    
    app/models/message.rb:13:in `initialize'
    app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:11:in `new'
    app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:11:in `create'

Comment: ok i change the @message = set_message without the : and is working well